# How to add Place to Video Uploaded via PHP SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-winjs-sdk

I want to add Place to videos,
Videos Are Uploaded by PHP SDK

How can I do This ?

`'Place'=>'place id';` This Code  work for Photos But Dont Work for Videos

Comment: hey man can you add your solution. This still not worked for me. i'm using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=%7Bpage-id%7D&version=v2.5 for test

Comment: I'm publishing the video without place using `/me/videos`. Apparently for this case says to do with `feed`. But I'm not sure this is the problem

Comment: can you helpe in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340128/add-current-location-posting-video-in-facebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know (and the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/ say the same), it isn't possible to add a `Place` with a `Video` at all.

You could create a separate Post after the upload, and add the Video `object_id` as well as the `Place` id accordingly. See the docs for Posts here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/

Comment: Thanks Tobi ;

object_id
The ID of any uploaded photo or video attached to the post.

I will upload video and retrive video id, Then Create new post and set place add object_id (uploaded video)

Thats work for me Thanks..