# Add current location posting video in facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, share

I need send the location in a post in facebook using the `place` key.
As shown [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/video)

At first I thought I had to send an object with the latitude and longitude into a location called key.

Then I realized that you have to send in one `place` key `place_id`

Managed to get the closest place_id with this

```
NSMutableDictionary *params2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:4L];
    
    [params2 setObject:@"37.416382,-122.152659" forKey:@"center"]; //Hard code coordinates for test
    [params2 setObject:@"place" forKey:@"type"];
    [params2 setObject:@"1000" forKey:@"distance"];
    
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/search" parameters:params2 HTTPMethod:@"GET"] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"RESPONSE!!! /search");
        NSLog(@"result %@",result);
        NSLog(@"error %@",error);
    }];
```

So, when i tried to send a post using `/me/videos` with the location, a error appear.

`(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.`

Here my code.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:4L];
    
    [params setObject:videoData forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.MOV",title]];
    [params setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
    [params setObject:desc forKey:@"description"];
    
    [params setObject:@"110503255682430" forKey:@"place"];// hard code for test
    
    NSString *privacyString = @"EVERYONE";
    if (privacy.length > 0)
        privacyString = privacy;
    
    NSDictionary *privacyDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: privacyString, @"value", nil];
    [params setObject:[Utils objectToJsonString:privacyDict] forKey:@"privacy"];

    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/me/videos" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        
        NSLog(@"RESPONSE!!! /me/videos");
        NSLog(@"result %@",result);
        NSLog(@"error %@",error);
        
        if (!error) {
             //video posted
             [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Your clip was posted!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
         } else {
             [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
         }
     }];
```

Thanks, any help will be appreciated

**EDITED:**

It seems to add a place, need to do an update after creating a video
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/video#Updating

But though I can update title, description, etc. It was impossible to add a place

**EDITED 2:**

I needed to add that permission `user_videos`.
***Now the response is success, but I do not see reflected the location in the video post***

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/videos#Creating does not mention a place parameter for video uploads.

Comment: Then it is impossible ?, there is any way?